# XML - How to pull out repeating children nodes

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, children

I am trying to extract repeating child elements from an xpath.

This is a sample of the XML:

```
              <productDetail>
                 <productTypeCode>123</productTypeCode>
                 <productPrice currency="EUR">13.27</productPrice>
                 <productPrice currency="US">15</productPrice>
              </productDetail>
```

As you can see the productPrice currency node is repeating.

I am able to pull out one of them by looping through each of the elements:

```
        @node.children.each do |c|
          if c.name == "productDetail"

             info = {}
              productTypeCode = nil

             c.children.each do |gc|
                  name = gc.name

                  if name == "productTypeCode" 
                     productTypeCode = gc.text
                  elsif name == "productPrice"
                     info["productPrice"] = gc.text
                     attrs = gc.attributes
                     info["productPrice_cur"] = attrs["currency"].value
                  end
```

As you can see I only have the "productPrice" information once in the loop, but there are two of them in the XML data.

How do I access both of the values, seen as the xpath and value names are the same?

I am coding this in Ruby.

Comment: Most likely your loop does iterate over two productPrice nodes, but you're storing the match in a dictionary. The second value overrides the first. Try adding in print statement in the loop to verify if this is the case.

Comment: Hi, yes that is the case. I printed out the values for "attrs" and it showed both "EUR" and "US" in the print. How do I store them separately?

Comment: I have no experience with Ruby, but I assume that there is some list (or array) like data type, which you can use to store your productPrice information.

Comment: Yes I am storing the details in a hash map (called "info" - in the code above). I will give it a try. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Store prices as an array: `(info["productPrice"] ||= []) << gc.text`.